# Interaction between Android Tablet to Android Phone and Android Tablet to Headphone/Helmet via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-profile

Bluetooth communication should happen between Android Tablet, Android Phone and Headphone/Headset/Helmet.

**Android Phone:** Responsible to send Incoming call and Media Infotainment data to the Android System (Tablet).

**Android System (Tablet):** is responsible to take actions [Media: (Play/Pause/Next/Previous) and Phone call: (Accept, Reject, Silence)] based on the data received from the Android Phone. Also send Map navigation instruction to the Headset/Helmet.

[image: Bluetooth Communication Flow]

What I had tried so far,
[RFCOMM connection between Android Table and Phone](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothChat) that send and receive data to and from Tablet to Phone. But doesn't allow to control phone to take actions sent from Tablet.

**Possible approach**

- Bluetooth Headset profile will do the same thing, so any way to set Bluetooth profile while connection between Tablet and Phone will solve the Media and Incoming phone call requirements.

Is these possible? If so what are the possibilities to achieve the same?